# Adding Checkmark on click, removing all others

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a ng-repeat with a button that looks like this:

```
<div data-ng-repeat="department in departments_array">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 dslc-button-wrapper">
            <button class="btn btn-default btn-block">Show on Map {{ 1 | checkmark }}</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have found this filter, which I would like to use to display a checkbox when the selected element is clicked, and remove all other checkmarks from the other ng-repeat buttons at the same time:

```
angular.module('Filters', []).filter('checkmark', function() {
  return function(input) {
    return input ? '\u2713' : '';
  };
});
```

I've tried as many ways as I know how, but I've only managed to end up with being able to add or remove the checkmark on one element at a time.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I wouldn't use a filter to do this.  It's not the correct way of managing state in your view.  A variable on your controller is a typical and readable solution.  Solution Below with [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/aJazW3?p=preview):

**controller.js**

```
myApp.controller('myController', function() {
  var self = this;
  self.departments_array = ['dept A', 'dept B', 'dept C'];
  self.selected_dept = undefined;
});
```

**index.html**

```
  <body ng-app="my-app">
    <div ng-controller="myController as mc">
      <div data-ng-repeat="department in mc.departments_array">
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-6 dslc-button-wrapper">
                  <button ng-click="mc.selected=department" class="btn btn-default btn-block">
                    Show on Map <span ng-show="mc.selected===department">&#10003;</span></button>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Comment: I don't know how this code works, I am used to using $scope in my controllers. Could you please expand or help me apply this using $scope?

Comment: Is using the controller as syntax.  Check out the Plunker.  Basically all that's different is that when you declare the controller you declare it as ``ng-controller="myController as mc"``  Then all child scope variables are prefixed with mc.  In the controller anything you add to this. is the same as the old way of doing $scope.

Comment: Please could you have a look at this plunker? I still can't get it to work:
https://plnkr.co/edit/TNp6N5yBuee5sUeR295h?p=preview

Comment: Fixed it - https://plnkr.co/edit/Mqq8bWiiEgpvMH5Cv4uL?p=info  various issues with it from no $scope, incorrect variables names etc.

Comment: This solution does not remove the original checkmark?

Comment: See updated plunker $parent was needed because ng-repeat creates a new child scope. - https://plnkr.co/edit/HTDMDPP0RjTJJ2qfvtAQ?p=preview